# c#, database has deleted, but didnt update when i go showdatatable or rebuild solution

Tags: c#, sql, database

[image] 
So the problem is, when execute, it show successful update, n if i debug again, it really did delete, but when i rebuild solution or go to view datatable, it show didnt deleted the row, how i enable to delete the datarow?

```
private void Update_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            string deletequery = " DELETE FROM StudentBook WHERE BookREF = @Book_Ref ";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(deletequery, con))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter3 = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                con.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_Ref", Book_Ref.SelectedItem.ToString());
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                adapter3.Update(dt);
                dt.AcceptChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("update successful");

            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message));
    }
    Scan_lbl.Text = string.Empty;
    Scan_lbl.Select();
}
```

Comment: Please show us the connection string you're using - thanks!

Comment: connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mydatabase2.Properties.Settings.Mydatabase2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

Comment: i just name my connection as connectionstring <sql databse>

Comment: Show us the **actual** connection string (stored in the config) - not how you load it - we need to see what **values** you have in your connection string!

Comment: show complete code, if You assume id update-delete set something is wrong .... update command is ???

Comment: your `MessageBox.Show` will show whether the command deleted any rows or not.. you may want to double check the value that you are passing in the parameter as well.

Comment: How do you verify that the row is deleted?  Do you check in the database ? You can check what value is being passed to the where clause. Use profiler to see what query is being executed. Looks like the query has wrong value in the where clause which is not deleting any rows.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your `MessageBox` to give you more feedback:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string deletequery = " DELETE FROM StudentBook WHERE BookREF = @Book_Ref ";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(deletequery, con))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter3 = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_Ref", Book_Ref.SelectedItem.ToString());
            int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            adapter3.Update(dt);
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} rows deleted.", rowsAffected));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("no rows deleted, bookref: {0}", Book_Ref.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```